# SPWeb.Groups vs SPWeb.AssociatedGroups

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss

I've seen three types of group properties for an `SPWeb` object - `Groups`, `SiteGroups`, `AssociatedGroups`.

I understand that `SiteGroups` will fetch all the groups in the current site collection. But what is the difference between `Groups` and `AssociatedGroups`. MSDN definition says that `Groups` will get all the 'cross-site'(!) groups for that web site. `AssociatedGroups` are fairly easily to understand just from the very name.

So what does `Groups` return? Can somebody explain me with an example?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Groups` return all groups which have security roles assigned to the current site.

`AssociatedGroups` return all groups visible in the left menu of the `People and Group page`. Those groups may not have access to the current site (if the security settings do not inherit from parent site). In this case, some of them will not be listed in the `Groups` property.

To view the difference, in a subsite, create a new group without giving any permission. The group will be visible in the `AssociatedGroups` and Left menu, but will not be listed in `Groups` or Site Permissions page.

Answer (score -1):

I believe msdn has the answer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.sitegroups.aspx

Gets a collection that contains all the groups in the site collection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.groups.aspx

Gets a collection that contains all the groups for the website. The following code example uses the Groups property to return the collection of groups for a specified site in the current site collection.

Which means, the SPGroup has been used in (ie assigned a permission in) the SPWeb somewhere.

Comment: -1 - I've clearly asked Groups vs AssociatedGroups. Not SiteGroups vs Groups.